# Drawer does not open on first touch

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a header that should open a drawer once it is touched. However the current behaviour is that it shows immediately the Profile screen (the drawer does not open) on first touch. If you touch the header again then the drawer is actually shown.

```
import ...

const navigationOptions = (navigation) => {
  return {
    title: navigation.screenProps.t('app.title')
  }
}

const defaultNavigationOptionsWithHeader = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.backgroundColor,
    },
    headerTintColor: Colors.main,
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    headerRight: <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginRight: 10 }} onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}>
      <Ionicons
        name={Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? 'ios-menu'
          : 'md-menu'}
        size={40}
        color={Colors.main}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  }
}

const defaultNavigationOptionsWithoutHeader = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.backgroundColor,
    },
    headerTintColor: Colors.main,
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  }
}

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: navigationOptions
    },
    Registration: {
      screen: RegistrationScreen,
      navigationOptions: navigationOptions
    }
  }, {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultNavigationOptionsWithoutHeader
  });

const TabStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    App: {
      screen: TabNavigator,
      navigationOptions: navigationOptions
    }
  }, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultNavigationOptionsWithHeader
  }
);

const MenuStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    App: {
      screen: MenuNavigator,
      navigationOptions: navigationOptions
    }
  }, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultNavigationOptionsWithHeader
  }
);

const appNavigationOptions = (navigation) => {
  return {
    initialRouteName: 'Tab'
  }
}

const AppStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Tab: TabStack,
    Menu: MenuStack
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: appNavigationOptions
  }
)

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    Auth: AuthStack,
    App: AppStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));
```

Does anybody know what causes this issue? The menu navigator is defined as follows:

```
import ...

handleHome = (navigation) => {
  navigation.navigate('App')
}

handleLogout = (navigation) => {
  logout();
  navigation.navigate('Auth')
}

const config = Platform.select({
  web: { headerMode: 'screen' },
  default: {},
});

const navigationOptions = (navigation) => {
  return {
    header: null
  }
}

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Map: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: navigationOptions
    }
  },
  config
);

ProfileStack.navigationOptions = (navigation) => {
  return {
    drawerLabel: navigation.screenProps.t('loggedin.sidebar.profile'),
    drawerIcon: ({ focused }) => (<DrawerIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-contact'}`
          : 'md-contact'
      }
    />)
  };
}

ProfileStack.path = '';

const PreferencesStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Settings: {
      screen: PreferencesScreen,
      navigationOptions: navigationOptions
    }
  },
  config
);

PreferencesStack.navigationOptions = (navigation) => {
  return {
    drawerLabel: navigation.screenProps.t('loggedin.sidebar.preferences'),
    drawerIcon: ({ focused }) => (<DrawerIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-settings'}`
          : 'md-settings'
      }
    />)
  }
};

const LogoutStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Logout: {
      screen: () => null,
      navigationOptions: navigationOptions
    }
  },
  config
);

LogoutStack.navigationOptions = (navigation) => {
  return {
    drawerLabel: navigation.screenProps.t('button.logout'),
    drawerIcon: ({ focused }) => createDrawerIcon('log-out', focused)
  };
}

const TabStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Logout: {
      screen: () => null,
      navigationOptions: navigationOptions
    }
  },
  config
);

TabStack.navigationOptions = (navigation) => {
  return {
    drawerLabel: navigation.screenProps.t('app.title'),
    drawerIcon: ({ focused }) => createDrawerIcon('home', focused)
  };
}

createDrawerIcon = (icon, focused = false) => {
  return <DrawerIcon
    focused={focused}
    name={
      Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? 'ios-' + icon
        : 'md-' + icon
    }
  />
}

const MenuDrawerItem = (props) => {
  return <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} >
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
        {createDrawerIcon(props.icon)}
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.label}>{props.text}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity >
}

const MenuDrawer = (props) => (
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
      <MenuDrawerItem onPress={() => this.handleHome(props.navigation)} text={props.screenProps.t('app.title')} icon={'home'} />
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </SafeAreaView>
    <MenuDrawerItem onPress={() => this.handleLogout(props.navigation)} text={props.screenProps.t('button.logout')} icon={'log-out'} />
  </ScrollView>
);

const menuNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  ProfileStack,
  PreferencesStack
}, {
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    contentComponent: props => <MenuDrawer {...props} />,
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: Colors.main
    },
    initialRouteName: 'ProfileStack'
  }
);

menuNavigator.path = ''

export default menuNavigator

const styles = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably you might have something other in focus.
May be `Keyboard`, `TextField`, Or some other things which are in focus and when you click for the first time the focus gets removed and when you press for the second time the drawer gets opened.

Try calling an alert instead of opening the drawer on button press and then debug that. That will troubleshoot the issue